# How to sort varchar row by asc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column `Cardnumber` from `Employees` table. The row of a column contains the number of card: 0578391322177.

How can I sort the numbers in the row by asc and get 0112233577789?

The data type is `varchar`.

Comment: what's the data type

Comment: the data type is varchar

Comment: Ooff.. what database ? Got a numbers table hanging around?

Comment: noope:( just want to get know how to sort the values IN THE ROW. (not order by rows/tables)

Comment: Tag your database platform and version.

Comment: @PeakyEye I asked two questions..

Comment: Your question is missing some information. Please post sample input and output data. Does your table also contain the value `012233577789` on another row? Or are you trying to transform that value? Do you want this value to come first or last?

Comment: This question is equally as mystifying as your other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68626945/how-to-sort-a-row-in-sql Please take the time to post sample data

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Variable-length data types have a length, which you have not shared. `VarChar(1)` won't hold your sample string. Do you need a solution that works for `VarChar(max)` or some more reasonable length? What have you tried? Any research?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would have a *numbers or tally table* to hand; you can build one on the fly using a CTE however.

You can join this to a `substring` of each character, then recombine using `string_agg` and order appropriately. This is assuming the card numbers are all the same length - if not adjust the CTE and include a `where` criteria to be `<= len(string)`.

```
declare @n varchar(13)='0578391322177';

with digits as (
    select * 
    from (
      values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13)
   )v(n)
)
select String_Agg(n.d,'') within group (order by n.d)
from (
    select substring(@n,n,1)d
    from Digits
)n
```

> Output: 0112233577789

**Edit**
As an example of using with data from a table you would do

```
select Id, cardnumber, String_Agg(n.d,'') within group (order by n.d) SortedCardNumber
from (
    select t.Id, t.cardnumber, Substring(t.cardnumber,n,1)d 
    from 
    t cross join Digits d
    where d.n<=Len(t.cardnumber)
)n
    group by Id, cardnumber
```

See [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5118db8d4298d5358310c0fcea9b9b28)

Comment: There's a very real possibility the op can't generalise this to work for a column (which they did ask for), for example grouping by that column might not be intuitive to them. I think you may need to explicitly show the table based approach.

Comment: @MatBailie Fair point and I have added a version selecting columns from a table, Fiddle also updated.